# Which window managers support "detached" desktops?

Tags: window-manager, tiling-wm, virtual-desktop

## What do I mean by "detached"?

In the [herbstluftwm](https://herbstluftwm.org/) windows manager (and others, notably xmonad), the concept of a "virtual desktop" is removed from the physical monitors themselves. That means that any one monitor can be viewing any of the virtual desktops at a time.

As an example, let's say we had three screens:

`[SCREEN 1] | [SCREEN 2] | [SCREEN 3]`

and 3 VIRTUAL desktops (in reality it's 9).

`[VIRTUAL 1] | [VIRTUAL 2] | [VIRTUAL 3]`

Now, imagine I have virtual desktop 1 on screen 1, virtual desktop 2 on screen 2, and virtual desktop 3 on screen 3. I want to be able to change the view to:

`[VIRTUAL 2] | [VIRTUAL  1] | [VIRTUAL  3]`
without dragging or moving windows in any way.

herbstluftwm's rules are:

- If you switch to a VIRTUAL desktop not already on another physical screen, it replaces the focused monitor's VIRTUAL desktop with the one you want.
- If you switch to a VIRTUAL desktop that another screen is currently viewing, it will swap virtual desktops with that screen.
- The focus determines which monitor gets its VIRTUAL desktop changed. If you have focus on screen 2 and switch to virtual desktop 8, screen 2 views VIRTUAL desktop 8.

## What do other window managers do?

The only other environments I have extensive experience with are Gnome and KDE. In both cases, **each virtual desktop is really a set of N screens**.

So, with 3 screens and 3 VIRTUAL desktops, there are actually 9 "working areas".

If I switch to VIRTUAL desktop 2 while the second monitor is focused, all three screens will change since screens are "bound" to the virtual desktop. There is no separation of screen and desktop.

## What I'm asking

First of all, is there a name for this type of functionality? I cannot work without it, and if herbstluftwm never supports Wayland then I'll be stuck on X indefinitely to get this feature.

Second, which window managers support this? Are there hacks / workarounds where KDE or Gnome can behave like this?

Comment: Quick comment - 3 years after asking this question, I've found a sort of pseudo-workaround involving XFCE. It's not quite what this question is asking, but close enough. XFCE comes with an option to keep a window "Always on virtual workspace". This isn't as powerful as herbstluftwm's feature, but it's enough to keep 1 window eternally on another screen. Which is better than GNOME / KDE's default behavior of keeping Workspaces entirely separate.